# ListView item adapter cannot click

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, adapter

i cannot click on an item inside my listview, all of this happened all of a sudden. i have been working on this for a week now, but before that, it has no problem at all. i could click on an item.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), list.get(i).getPassword(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});

CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.cardview_layout_locked, list);                            
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
tools:context=".LobbyFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lobbieslistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

this is my customlistadapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<cardviewTest> {

private static final String TAG = "CustomListAdapter";

private Context mContext;
private int mResource;
private int lastPosition = -1;

/**
 * Holds variables in a View
 */
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView lobbyTextView, organizerTextView;
    ImageView image;
}

/**
 * Default constructor for the PersonListAdapter
 * @param context
 * @param resource
 * @param objects
 */

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<cardviewTest> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    mContext = context;
    //mResource = resource;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //sets up the image loader library
    setupImageLoader();

    //get the persons information
    String lobbyname = getItem(position).getLobbyname();
    String organizer = getItem(position).getOrganizer();
    String imgUrl = getItem(position).getImageURL();
    String password = getItem(position).getPassword();

    try{


        //create the view result for showing the animation
        final View result;

        //ViewHolder object
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){

            if(!password.equals("") || password!=null){ this.mResource = R.layout.cardview_layout_locked; }
            if(password.equals("") || password==null){ this.mResource = R.layout.cardview_layout; }

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
            holder= new ViewHolder();
            holder.organizerTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.organizerTV);
            holder.lobbyTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lobbynameTV);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

            result = convertView;

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }


        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
                (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.load_down_anim : R.anim.load_up_anim);
        result.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;

        holder.organizerTextView.setText(organizer);
        holder.lobbyTextView.setText(lobbyname);

        //create the imageloader object
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        int defaultImage = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/image_failed",null,mContext.getPackageName());

        //create display options
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(defaultImage)
                .showImageOnFail(defaultImage)
                .showImageOnLoading(defaultImage).build();

        //download and display image from url
        imageLoader.displayImage(imgUrl, holder.image, options);

        return convertView;
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "getView: IllegalArgumentException: " + e.getMessage() );
        return convertView;
    }
}

/**
 * Required for setting up the Universal Image loader Library
 */
private void setupImageLoader(){
    // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            mContext)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
}
}
```

i completely have no idea on what was the reason why i can't click on items anymore. all of these just happened in a sudden. this was working, just a month ago, then, this happened

Comment: I suggest you use **RecyclerView**  instead of  **ListView**

Comment: cant figure the problem but for instance try creating an interface implement that interface in your fragmnet or activity then pass interface to adapter in constructor  and set Click listener on convertView and in onlick method call the method of the interface

Answer (score 0):

No errors found in your codes, please check `CustomListAdapter` class file to see if disabled item.

**Edited**
Notice:

```
//download and display image from url
imageLoader.displayImage(imgUrl, holder.image, options);
```

above lines are time consuming, which will block UI thread, don't place these in `CustomListAdapter` .

You could create an interface. trigger the interface callbackwhen click listview item , and handle things in callback. There are lots of sample about custom adapter,please google.

Comment: i cant select a row in the listview, i dont understand. this happened all of a sudden

Comment: create a new and clean project, or post CustomListAdapter codes.

Comment: i've updated my question and added my customlistadapter. please have a look

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would set the `Adapter` and stuff first then handling the clicks on the `ListView` items:

```
CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.cardview_layout_locked, list);                            
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), list.get(i).getPassword(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

Also, try making these two as `true`;

```
android:focusable=“true”
android:focusableInTouchMode=“true”
```

Then it should work i hope.

---

Also, consider using `RecyclerView` nowadays.

Comment: still the same i cant press the items, any other ideas? please help

Comment: The `FrameLayout`, you are showing the `Fragment` by `FrameLayout` and a List under. Consider showing `Fragment` by `FrameLayout` in the MainActivity layout (It can be with `CoordinatorLayot` and `FrameLayout`) then using `ListView` inside `Fragment`. So, for now, It’s actually outside of the `Fragment`.